# How to use local packages with swift build

Tags: swift

I"m new to swift and gradually learning its tricks. I would like to find out how to add dependency to local package. I did the following:

1. I created two packages TestA and TestB using `swift package init --type executable`
2. I changed `Package.swift` in `TestB` to use `.package(path: "../TestA")` in package dependencies and when I compile the `TestB` package it complained as following:

```
'TestA' /Users/vk/Work/Languages/Swift/tmp/TestA: error: package 'TestA' contains no products
warning: dependency 'TestA' is not used by any target
```

3. Then I initialized `TestA` with git and added a tag,

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git tag 1.0.0
```

and then I used `.package(url: "../TestA", from: "1.0.0")` in its `Package.swift` to add dependency. This time the build resolved local package but complained almost identically

```
Fetching /Users/vk/Work/Languages/Swift/tmp/TestA
Cloning /Users/vk/Work/Languages/Swift/tmp/TestA
Resolving /Users/vk/Work/Languages/Swift/tmp/TestA at 1.0.0
'TestA' /Users/vk/Work/Languages/Swift/tmp/TestB/.build/checkouts/TestA: error: package 'TestA' contains no products
```

So, how we can add local packages to the swift build?
Thanks,
Valentin.

Comment: TestA should be created as `--type framework` and contains at least a function. In TestB you need to `import TestA` (do not know if you need to call the function form TestA to silence the warnings)

Comment: ok, what if TestA is a git repository I clone, how I can convert it to type framework? Here is what I see:
`swift package init --type framework` 

`error: unknown value 'framework' for argument --type; use --help to print usage` Then if I use help:

`swift package init --help`

`OVERVIEW: Initialize a new package`

`OPTIONS:`

`  --name   Provide custom package name`

`  --type   empty|library|executable|system-module|manifest`

Comment: Sorry… `library`, not framework (then they will create a bundle under framework folders, hence the misanderstood)! 
As far as i know you can't import an executable in a second project, the packages dependencies are supposed to be library (frameworks) like the native UIKit or Foundation. If you find an executable in Git you don't take it as a dependency, but clone it and change it directly to your porpouse.